# Replace multiple strings in a file with Powershell

Tags: powershell, replace, find

We want to replace multiple instances of the variable `id=*`, with a certain pattern, like `id=1234`.
I already made this Powershell script (and prefer to keep using Powershell as solution):

```
$line = Get-Content C:\test.txt | Select-String "id=" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
$content = Get-Content C:\test.txt
$content | ForEach {$_ -replace $line,"id=1234"} | Set-Content C:\test.txt
Get-Content C:\test.txt
```

This works, as long as there's only 1 instance of `id=...`, when a file contains multiple instances of `id=...` there is no replacement step performed at all.

The input file is similar to:

```
text over here
id=1
text over here: id={123456}
text
id=number1
id=#3 text 
id=3+3 text
```

which should result in:

```
text over here
id=1234
text over here: id=1234
text
id=1234
id=1234 text 
id=1234 text
```

Comment: So replace id= and any characters that follow that until the end of the line? `(Get-Content C:\test.txt) | ForEach {$_ -replace "id=.*","id=1234"}`

Comment: A variant with a [positive  lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(gc C:\test.txt) -replace '(?<=id=)[^\s]+','1234'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to capture every characters after `id=` until you hit a whitespace.

The following will work just fine

```
$content = Get-Content "C:test.txt" -raw
$content = $content -replace 'id=[^\s]*','id=1234'
Set-Content C:\test.txt
Get-Content C:\test.txt
```

Using the `-Raw` parameter will load the file quickly into a string instead of an array.
From there, using the replace above, you will get the desired result.

The `[^\s]*` is to match a single character NOT including a character of whitespace (space, tab, carriage return, line feed)

You can use RegexStorm when creating regex statements.

[See the regex I provided tested on there.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=id%3D%5B%5E%5Cs%5D*&i=text%20over%20here%0D%0Aid%3D1%0D%0Atext%20over%20here%3A%20id%3D%7B123456%7D%0D%0Atext%0D%0Aid%3Dnumber1%0D%0Aid%3D%233%20text%20%0D%0Aid%3D3%2B3%20text%20)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do:

Read the text as string array and replace line-by-line:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\test.txt') | 
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '(id\s*=\s*[^\s]+)', 'id=1234' } | 
    Add-Content -Path 'C:\test_updated.txt'
```

or read the text in as a single string and perform a Multiline replace (`(?m)`)

```
(Get-Content C:\test.txt -Raw) -replace '(?m)(id\s*=\s*[^\s]+)', 'id=1234' | 
    Set-Content -Path 'C:\test_updated.txt'
```

I strongly recommend using a new filename for the output file so you do not overwrite the original.

In both cases, the code returns:

> ```
> text over here
> id=1234
> text over here: id=1234
> text
> id=1234
> id=1234 text 
> id=1234 text
> ```

**Regex Details**

```
(            Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   id        Match the characters “id” literally
   \s        Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
      *      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   =         Match the character “=” literally
   \s        Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
      *      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   [^\s]     Match any character that is NOT a “A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)”
      +      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```